# How can I scrape an interactive map with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I have a page like this: https://www.enel.com.co/es/personas/mantenimientos-programados.html

[image]

And my idea is to do web sraping to be able to extract the data from all the "jobs" to later save them as dictionaries and populate a nosql database. The question is only directed to scraping, how could I extract the data from this map? From what I think, it is being loaded through javascript dynamically, so I have been thinking if it could be done through request or if I would have to use something like selenium.
I have some notion of web scraping, but I am not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access their API directly:

```py
import requests


def get_map_data() -> dict:
    r = requests.post(
        'https://www.enel.com.co/es/personas/mantenimientos-programados.mdwedgeohl.getDataScheduledOutages.html',
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Referer': 'https://www.enel.com.co/es/personas/mantenimientos-programados.html',
        },
        data=dict(
            src='/content/dam/enel-co/español/personas/mantenimientos-programados/2023/abril/actualizacion_cortes_25042023.csv',
            functionality='map-public-area',
        ),
    )
    return r.json()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_map_data())
```

Output:

```bash
{'markers': [{'lat': '4.628958139', 'lon': '-74.19018624', 'desc': {'beginning': '26/04/2023 7:15:00 a. m. hrs', 'ending': '26/04/2023 5:15:00 p. m. hrs', 'type': '1', 'address': 'CA...
```

Comment: Great, could you explain me how you got the "src" and "functionality" parameters? Thanks!!!

Comment: If you go to devtools in your browser (F12) and navigate to `network` tab, you can find all requests your browser makes while loading the page. Parameters you're looking for are in `payload` section of URL in my answer.